# Column reference ambiguous but it is actually a function parameter

Tags: postgresql

I'm getting the following error and can't seem to find a resolution beyond changing the argument names which I would rather not do:

```
ERROR:  column reference "pcode" is ambiguous
LINE 2:         where lower(n.pcode) = lower(pCode)
```

`pCode` is an argument for the plpgsql function and `n.pcode` is a column from the table with the alias of n.

It looks something like this:

```
create or replace function func_name(
    pCode text,
    other_params....
)
returns json as
$$
declare
q text;
x bigint;
begin

    if pCode is not null and param_x is not null then
        select count(*) from n_table n
        where lower(n.pcode) = lower(pCode)
        and lower(n.param_x) = lower(param_x)
        into x;
        RAISE NOTICE 'returned amount: %', x;
    end if;

etc, etc
```

The above will work if I change `pCode` to say `pCode123` but this isn't an ideal solution for me. Is there any way that I can explicitly tell it that `lower(pCode)` references that function parameter and not the column?

I will have the same issue with `param_x` which is spelt exactly the same as the column name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a column named `pcode` and a parameter named `pcode` a reference to just `pcode` is thus ambiguous.

Most people just choose some prefix for their arguments to avoid this situation (e.g. `arg_pcode` or `p_pcode`). If you don't want to change your parameter `pcode` to something different, you can [fully qualify](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html) it with the function's name:

```
lower(func_name.pcode)
```